# numpy sliding dot matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm using numpy to do some matrix operations and I'm unsure on how to achieve a particular operation on the following two matrices:

```
(a)                       (b)          (c)
[1                     [1 -1 0         [2
 1   (some operation)   1 -1 0      =  -3
 1                      0 -1 0          0
 1]                     0  0 0]         0]
```

So essentially I want to have an equivalently shaped matrix as (a), but with every entry being the entry in (a), "dotted" with the column in (b) it corresponds to.

I'm currently using the following but it seems rather hacky and only gets me scalars and I feel like there must be a better way:

```
np.dot(a , np.atleast_2d(b[0].T[0]))[0].sum() = 2
etc...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Since `b` only has 3 columns then there are only 3 inner products to compute over the columns of `a` and `b`: `a[:, 0].dot(b[:, 0])`,  `a[:, 0].dot(b[:, 1])` and `a[:, 0].dot(b[:, 2])`, so I don't see how you could end up with an output the same shape as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialise your data like this:

```
b=np.zeros((4,3))
a=np.ones((4,1))
b[0:2,0]=1
b[0:3,1]=-1
```

You can use `dot`:

```
  np.dot(a.T,b)
```

giving

```
array([[ 2., -3.,  0.]])
```

Almost what you want. Your problem is that you have no 4th column in `b` corresponding to the 4th element in `a`. You could append a `0` to the result or append a column of zeros to `b` to get around this. Or:

```
c=np.zeros_like(a)
c[0:3]=np.dot(a.T,b).T
```